# CAML Query to get only non duplicates

Tags: sharepoint-2013, caml

My first goal is to get all items that has a status of `'Pending'` in my `sharepoint list`. My code so far is like this :

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(spSite.Trim()))
            {
                clientContext.Credentials = GetNetworkCredential();
                var approvalLists = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(approvalLibraryName);

                CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
                query.ViewXml = "<View>" +
                                    "<Query>" +
                                       "<Where>" +
                                           "<Eq>" +
                                               "<FieldRef Name='IsApproved'/><Value Type='Choice'>Pending</Value>" +
                                           "</Eq>" +
                                       "</Where>" +
                                   "</Query>" +
                               "</View>";

                ListItemCollection approvalListItem = approvalLists.GetItems(query);
                clientContext.Load(approvalListItem);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            }
```

It is working but I then realize that a particular item can be inserted more than 1 in that list. So for example for item `request_100`, it can have one row for `pending` and another row for `approved`. So I need to only get those non duplicates items with status `'Pending'`. Is it possible to have group by then fetch only those who have count = 1? Because I'm thinking if I could just load all items then manipulate it in using linq list. Or do you guys have another suggestion for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought was indeed also using linq on the ItemCollection which should be working just fine.

But just a thought, if you select only the 'pending' rows, you won't get duplicates will you? Or can there be more than one item like 'request_100' with statusses 'Pending'?

Check this question which is alike to yours: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43262/how-to-use-groupby-in-caml-query

Comment: There are request_100 with diff status for some reason. For example at first request_100 will be 'Pending' then when it gets 'Approved' it will have another row. So getting items using Caml query with filter to get only those 'Pending' can't check if that request_100 as 'Pending' is obsolete. Using group by is I guess I can also use.  Thank you